# Got an error when I run API in the initstate and cannot get the desired output

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am working on a project where I am creating the selecting interests screen where user can select 5 interests. I am getting interest after calling the API and then I got **id** and **value** (value is the title of interest) if the user selects following interest i have to send corresponding id's to the backend. I created the function of getData to get `List<Map<String, dynamic>> options` and then call it in initstate but getting the below mentioned error. I need help in solving the following problem. Thank you.

**Code:**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> options = [];

void getData() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> tempData = [];
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: LoadingAnimationWidget.discreteCircle(
            color: const Color(0XFF00B251),
            size: 50,
            secondRingColor: const Color(0XFFF8B32B),
            thirdRingColor: const Color(0XFFF72A37),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    var response = await Auth().getInterests();
    Navigator.pop(context);
    if (response['statusCode'] == 200) {
      for (int i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++) {
        tempData.add({
          'id': response['data'][i]['_id'],
          'value': response['data'][i]['title']
        });
      }
    } else {
      displayErrorMotionToast(context, response['message']);
    }
    setState(() {
      options = tempData;
    });
}

@override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
}



//UI CODE
Wrap(
      children: options.map(
        (value) {
          bool isSelected = false;
          if (interests.contains(value['id'])) {
            isSelected = true;
          }
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (!interests.contains(value['id'])) {
                if (interests.length < 5) {
                  interests.add(value['id']);
                  setState(() {});
                }
              } else {
                interests
                    .removeWhere((element) => element == value['id']);
                setState(() {});
              }
            },
            child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 7.5,
                  vertical: 5,
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  ...                    ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 ...
                ),
                child: Text(
                  value['value'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    ...
                  ),
                )),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    ),
```

**Error:**

```
E/flutter ( 5404): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _InterestState.initState() completed.
E/flutter ( 5404): When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
E/flutter ( 5404): Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.
E/flutter ( 5404): #0      StatefulElement.dependOnInheritedElement.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5704:9)
E/flutter ( 5404): #1      StatefulElement.dependOnInheritedElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5747:6)
E/flutter ( 5404): #2      Element.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #3      Localizations.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart:529:48)
E/flutter ( 5404): #4      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:92:23)
E/flutter ( 5404): #5      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:113:4)
E/flutter ( 5404): #6      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:1413:10)
E/flutter ( 5404): #7      _InterestState.getData (package:communify/Screens/Registration/Sign%20Up/interests.dart:66:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #8      _InterestState.initState (package:communify/Screens/Registration/Sign%20Up/interests.dart:131:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5602:55)
E/flutter ( 5404): #10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #18     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #19     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #29     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #40     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #41     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #42     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #43     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #44     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #45     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #47     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #48     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #49     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #50     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #51     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #52     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #53     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #54     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #55     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #56     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #58     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #59     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #60     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #61     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #62     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #63     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #64     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #65     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #66     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #67     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #68     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #69     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #70     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #71     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #72     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #73     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #74     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #75     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #77     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #78     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #79     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #80     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #81     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #82     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #83     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #84     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #85     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #86     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #87     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #88     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #89     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #90     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #91     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #92     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #93     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #94     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #95     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #96     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #97     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #98     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #99     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #100    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #101    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #102    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #103    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #104    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #105    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #106    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #107    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #108    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #109    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #110    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #111    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #113    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #114    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #115    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #116    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #117    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #118    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #119    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #120    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #121    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #122    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #123    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #124    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #125    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #126    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #127    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #128    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #129    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #130    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #131    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #132    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #133    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #134    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #135    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #136    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #137    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #138    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #139    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #140    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #141    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #142    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #143    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #144    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #145    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #146    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #147    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #148    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #149    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #150    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #151    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #152    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #153    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #154    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #155    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #156    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #157    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #158    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #159    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #160    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #161    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #162    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6736:14)
E/flutter ( 5404): #163    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #164    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #165    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #166    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #167    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #168    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #169    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #170    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #171    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #172    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #173    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #174    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #175    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #176    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #177    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #178    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #179    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #180    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #181    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #182    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #183    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #184    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #185    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #186    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #187    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #188    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #189    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #190    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #191    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #192    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
E/flutter ( 5404): #193    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5496:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #194    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #195    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter ( 5404): #196    ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5453:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #197    StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5625:11)
E/flutter ( 5404): #198    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5447:5)
E/flutter ( 5404): #199    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4326:16)
E/flutter ( 5404): #200    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3837:18)
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to show a dialog inside initState? That's not possible. Can you edit the question to include that code?

Comment: @RichardHeap I edited the code.

Comment: You cannot `showDialog` in `initState`. You should probably be doing that from build, but it's not clear why you need a dialog in getData.

Comment: I have done this in many places, thats because getting data may take long so the loader is visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally Such Tasks can be done using the business logic and in the builder method. But we don't live in an ideal world?

Solution to your problem is simply to let the first frame of UI to render first.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getData());
```

Use this in your `initState`.
Quoting this from https://ankitgg66.medium.com/addpostframecallback-338316ca3207

> The addPostFrameCallback method is a part of the WidgetsBinding class
> which is inherited from SchedulerBinding in Flutter. It allows
> developers to register a callback that will be invoked after the
> current frame finishes rendering. The callback receives a timestamp
> parameter indicating the time at which it was called.